# Перестал запускаться chrome на Debian

Tags: google-chrome, debian

Сегодня, после того как комп вырубился по перегреву, перестал запускаться Сhrome на Debian. При попытке запуска из консоли выдает следующее.

```
kraamis@kr-deb [~]$ google-chrome
[1615:1615:0415/230610.283005:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(375)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[1569:1596:0415/230618.708083:ERROR:in_progress_cache_impl.cc(93)] Could not read download entries from file because there was a read failure.
Gkr-Message: 23:06:18.925: secret service operation failed: The name org.freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files
```

До этого все работало. Debian - Testing со всеми обновлениями. Переустанавливать браузер уже пробовал несколько раз, сносил подчистую через `apt-get purge`. Ставил и через dpkg в консоли, и через GDebi.

Всезнающий гугл сказал, что пару раз такое возникало за всю историю багтрекинга, но с рецептами решения - вилы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло удалений конфигов `~/.config/chrome`

Похоже что purge не трет конфиги созданные при запуске программы.

update. Не помогло. На следующий день все по новой. Плюнул и переустановил.